# Java Web Start NumberFormatException while running Jar application

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, numberformatexception

While trying to run Jar application using JWS (JNLP) launch. It has been giving me this error. Can't even find where is the mistake. Any directions would help.

If someone could tell me where is the potential location of this error, I could find post that code here.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "\Tools_Dev\TestApp\dist"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebaseEx(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Note:** I have the latest Java 8 installed and working on Netbeans.
The jar file works well if called manually, java -jar testTool.jar

**Update:**

**JNLP File Content:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="file:/C:/Tools_Dev/TestApp/dist/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>Java Tool Update Test</title>
        <vendor>Local</vendor>
        <description>Test Tool</description>
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <update check="background"/>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="Java-Tool-Update-Test.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-M1.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jaxen-1.1.6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="Tool.Test.Main">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

**Errors prompted in JaNeLa tool excluding warnings and optimizations:**

```
JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-M1.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar unless the download 'part' is specified. 
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for lib/jaxen-1.1.6.jar unless the download 'part' is specified.
```

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/?tab=co&authuser=0#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Thanks pretty nice application. Found lots of problems in the JNLP file created by Netbeans. Now the problem is how to fix them :-)
One by one, way to go.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Sorry for the question is comment. The page for [help here](http://pscode.org/janela/help.html) is not working. Any idea why and how can I get this help for the errors reported by JaNeLa tool.

Comment: My bad about the help link, it is to a site that no longer exists.  I should rebuild the Jar to include that page.  But in the meantime, why not post the text report JaNeLA produces as an edit to the question?  I can have a look over it and provide further advice.  BTW - You can ignore all the warnings and optimizations reported.  It is only the errors that are of interest at this point.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: that's nice. Just updated the question with JNLP file contents and JaNeLa Report, thanks :-)

Comment: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element`  Usually this means the elements are not in the correct order.  Try moving the element up in the JNLP one spot at a time till the error disappears or changes to another element.

Comment: `cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'application-desc' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.`  Huh.. first time I've seen that one.  But it seems that `<application-desc main-class="Tool.Test.Main">Test Tool</application-desc>` should be `<application-desc main-class="Tool.Test.Main"/>`  - `Test Tool` is already specified as the `description` in any case.

Comment: Yes you are totally right, I added that part myself, stupid editing. Updating the question again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57666/discussion-between-indigo-and-andrew-thompson).

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest JNLP?  Also I don't 'chat', even when the site suggests it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Just updated the question with latest JNLP. Basically just the application-desc value is removed. Yes, I got the suggestion, that's why clicked on it. :-)

Comment: Note: `file:/C:/Tools_Dev//TestApp/dist/` should not have a `//`, just all `/`.  Also try moving the `security` element above the `update` element!

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Just tried the changes. Unfortunately still the same problem. NumberFormatException

Comment: It finally worked now. In Netbeans, I set user defined HTTP deployment and set the link to our server. Keeping all other libs to Eager mode. But nothing really happened after it downloaded the files. But, I can't even find where did it downloaded the files.

Comment: Be sure the [Java Console](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show when debugging applets or JWS apps.

Comment: This is another problem I am facing now. I have configured this but still it wouldn't open Java console. Even if I double click on a jar file. So finally I have to do it manually as java -jar testTool.jar

Either I have become lazy working in Visual Studio and C# or Configuring java is rally dificult for an amature developer :-D

Answer (score 4):

Posting this here in case someone has that very same error, even with java 8 Update 101:

In our specific case, after a few hours of digging, the problem ended up being  that NetBeans version 7.4 was putting some useless junk on the `Codebase` property of the jar's `MANIFEST.MF`; by going into the project properties, `Application -> Web Start` and then changing `Codebase`  to `User defined` and `Codebase Preview` to `*`, the application started working correctly.

Please do keep in mind that we're using an applet instead of a JNLP application, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I used "http://localhost:1234/" instead of "*"  as this populates the JNLP's location in the file. Cheers for tip.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a known issue... See [Bug #236765](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236765)

Upgrading your Java version as specified in the bug.

> Not a NB issue, javaws problem. I've tested
>   https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/javase-jws.html with JDK 1.7.0_45 and 
>   works fine.Please update JDK   JRE.

Comment: I have the latest Java 8 Update 5
Guess that's not the problem, but yes this is happening using Netbeans in my case as well.