# Java Web Start NetBeans Bug?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-web-start, jnlp

I am trying to make a Java Web Start application using the Web Start tool in NetBeans 8.0. I followed [the directions from NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/javase-jws.html), but I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "\Users\maxerdwien\Desktop\ConverterPrj\ConverterPrj\dist"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebaseEx(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verifyCodebase(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.AppPolicy.grantUnrestrictedAccess(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This problem is a [closed bug of NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=236765#c2) and has been [discussed on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828641/java-web-start-numberformatexception-while-running-jar-application), but I am using Java 7 update 65. I suspect that the reason it worked for Tomas Zezula (who closed the bug) is that he did not set the project configuration to 'Web Start'. This step is not stated in the NetBeans tutorial, but without it NetBeans will bypass the jnlp entirely and just run the jar.

The program works when run from the jar directly.

I have determined that the 'input string' is not coming from the codebase property in the jnlp; I suspect it is coming from the manifest.

Any advice on how to fix this within NetBeans or outside it would be very appreciated.

Edit: Here is the generated jnlp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="file:/C:/Users/maxerdwien/Desktop/ConverterPrj/ConverterPrj/dist/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>ConverterPrj</title>
    <vendor>maxerdwien</vendor>
    <homepage href=""/>
    <description>ConverterPrj</description>
    <description kind="short">ConverterPrj</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<update check="background"/>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href="ConverterPrj.jar" main="true"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="Converter">
</application-desc>
```

Edit: And here is the report from JaNeLA:

```
JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17


Report for file:/C:/Users/maxerdwien/Desktop/ConverterPrj/ConverterPrj/dist/launch.jnlp

Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. One of '{resources, application-desc, applet-desc, component-desc, installer-desc}' is expected.
XML encoding not known, but declared as UTF-8
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'ConverterPrj.jar'.
The resource download at ConverterPrj.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for ConverterPrj.jar unless the download 'part' is specified.
```

Comment: So.. have you checked the JNLP using JaNeLA?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, I should have mentioned that. I did use your tool, and I have added the report to my question, along with the JNLP. The only lines in red in the report were the ones starting "cvc-complex". Changing the JNLP to put the <update> tag after the <security> tag causes those two lines to go away, but the error from trying to run the JNLP is the same.

Comment: Max, I'm in the same boat as you and haven't found a solution to this problem.  Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Sorry Phillip, I didn't find a solution.